# ¿Existen librerías oh clases de data mining(algoritmos de minería de datos) para C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, base-de-datos, visual-studio-2017

Lo que pasa que tengo un profesor medio especial de mi materia de Minería de datos que pues prefiere que hagamos nosotros mismos un programa para minar, tengo mis base de datos en sql server y pues necesito utilizar algunos algoritmos como clustering k-means, oh alguno de agrupamiento... Por lo que investigue  SQL Server Analysis Services nos da la facilidad de implementar esos algoritmos sobre los datos que hay en BD. Pero dado el problema que no puedo utilizar software especial para esto, tenia curiosidad sobre si existen librerías sobre esto, dada la escasez de información sobre el tema. Soy apenas estudiante de ingeniera en sistemas por lo que tengo un poco de complicación para entender como desarrollar un programa que cumpla con estas funciones.

De ante mano muchas gracias y gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour], asi entenderás un poco mejor como funciona el sitio y de paso obtendrás tu primera medalla. En tu pregunta dices: ***dado el problema que no puedo utilizar software especial para esto, tenia curiosidad sobre si existen librerías sobre esto*** lo cual me suena a contradicción, ya que cualquier librería que realice dicha tarea es considerada un software especial. La duda en todo caso la debes aclarar con tu profesor. Saludos

Comment: Que algoritmo de SQL Server Analysis Services pensabas utilizar ?

Comment: Con software especial me refiero a una herramienta de minería de datos, no confundas librería con software amigo. Las librerías son usadas por los lenguajes. Pensaba utilizar algún algoritmo como k-means, mi programa lo estoy desarrollando con c# en visual studio